# ImportError: No module named processing

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am developing a stand alone python script that will invoke methods from processing module.
I am seeing error "ImportError: No module named processing" on ubuntu.

Here is the code.

```
import PyQt4.QtGui
import PyQt4.QtCore
import PyQt4.Qsci

from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *
import os


import processing

print 'hello'
```

Comment: First guess would be that you don't have the ``processing`` module installed.

Comment: Or that it can't be found where python is looking for it. Try *sys.path.append('path\to\where\it\is')* before the import. If you can't find the path to where the processing module is then Chad is probably correct, download and install again paying attention to where it's installed.

Comment: Do you mean are trying to execute a standalone script out of box? without starting the QGIS GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How can I access `processing` with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-to-use-qgis-explode-lines-with-python/129974#129974). There I explain what needs to be included in a standalone script to run processing algorithms.