# Accessing QGIS processing with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, explode

I want to access the [explode lines function in Python](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_geometry_tools/explodelines.html#console-usage) outside of QGIS from a standalone script.

What module do I have to load in order to use it?

How can I access `processing`?

```
from qgis.core import *

layerInput = QgsVectorLayer('test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')

processing.runalg('qgis:explodelines', layerInput, 'temp.shp')
```

Comment: I think you have to use `import processing`.

Comment: @Joseph Sorry for not being specific: But I want to access it from a standalone script.

Comment: Ahh no worries :). In that case, apologies but I do not know as I always run it within QGIS. Hopefully others will advise.

Comment: Hi @ustroetz, did you manage to run this from your standalone script? I ask because I am also trying to run external scripts.

Comment: @Joseph No, I haven't

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE 24.04.2018:** 
See how to do this in QGIS v3.x [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279937/4972).

---

**For QGIS v2.x**

Finally found the proper way of running processing algorithms via standalone PyQGIS scripts.

Using Processing plugin version 2.2.0-2, you can try the following script:

```
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/home/user/.qgis2/python/plugins') # Folder where Processing is located
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

# Run the algorithm
layerInput = QgsVectorLayer('test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')
general.runalg('qgis:explodelines', layerInput, 'temp.shp')

# Exit applications
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
QApplication.exit()
```

Newer Processing versions could be located at `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins`, so you might need to use `sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')` accordingly.

*I found the working example in [Error: Algorithm not found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98174/error-algorithm-not-found/118394#118394), which is in turn based on [a Qgis-dev mailing-list discussion](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2014-January/029974.html).*

Comment: The processing plugin may not be at `'/home/user/.qgis2/python/plugins'`. You can find the location by opening QGIS and clicking `plugins/Manage and install plugins` scroll down to processing and you will see the installation location in the description.

Comment: I received lots of warnings about `cannot-create-a-qpixmap` with this stand alone function but I see you solved that too in this question  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188074/pyqgis-error-cannot-create-a-qpixmap-or-qwidget-when-no-gui-is-being-used/188089?noredirect=1#comment284492_188089

Comment: You can make the standalone script even more generic by dropping `layerInput` and changing the runalg line to: `general.runalg(*sys.argv[1:])` not to mention that this script can be the basis for parallel GIS processing as per this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119961/how-can-i-parallelise-embarrassingly-parallel-gis-operations-in-qgis-python

Comment: Is it possible to do the same framework but to run PLUGINS from a standalone Python (not inside QGIS)? I executed alglist() function and I cannot see my plugins installed in my QGIS in there...

Answer (score 4):

Until I get to work the generic way of doing it, I will tell you a workaround.

I use the Processing plugin version 2.2.0-2 (I suggest you to use this version), which is installed in `/home/germap/.qgis2/python/plugins/` on my computer. You need to know this folder location, because you import the processing module from there.

Since you know the provider (`qgis`) and the algorithm (`explodelines`), you can look at `/home/germap/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/` to take the explode lines script name: `Explode.py` This information allows you to import the algorithm directly to your Python standalone script.

So, open a Python console and copy the following script (I use GNU/Linux, so the environment variables are set by default, allowing me to import qgis and PyQt4 libraries in a breeze):

```
# Prepare the environment
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Tell Python where you will get processing from
sys.path.append('/home/germap/.qgis2/python/plugins')

# Reference the algorithm you want to run
from processing.algs.qgis.Explode import *
alg = Explode() 

# Set input and output
inLayer = QgsVectorLayer('/home/user/data/in.shp', 'input', 'ogr')
outLayer = '/home/user/data/out.shp'
alg.setParameterValue('INPUT', inLayer)
alg.setOutputValue('OUTPUT', outLayer)

# Run the algorithm
from processing.core.SilentProgress import SilentProgress
progress = SilentProgress()
alg.processAlgorithm(progress)
```

If you don't get error messages, that's it. The output layer has been saved in the output path you specified (`/home/user/data/out.shp`)

*Note: Regarding a generic way (i.e., calling algorithms by name), I've found some troubles that I need to solve before posting it. As soon as I get it to work, I'll post it.*