# PyQGIS couldn't import processing with standalone script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have read [Accessing `processing` with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/129513/41673). The problem is even with a sys.path.append it couldn't import processing.

Here is the code I used:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/file.shp', "BAT","ogr")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

    # Testing processing
    try :
        Processing.runalg("qgis:creategrid")
    except:
        print "Processing module has not been loaded"

    #Check the QgsMapLayerRegistry for the layers
    print QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    # Check if they are valid
    print layer.isValid()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from qgis.core import *
    app = QApplication([])
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    sys.path.append('home/qsuser/.qgis2/python/plugins')

    # try to load processing
    try:
        from processing.core.Processing import Processing
        Processing.initialize()

    except:
        print "unable to load processing"

    main()

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

I could load QGIS and layer is valid that's ok, but processing resist to me. I am on Ubuntu 14.04
I use `Pycharm` to do it.
I tried on terminal with the python console, it raised this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/qsuser/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from processing.tools.dataobjects import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/qsuser/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 35, in <module>
    from processing.core.ProcessingConfig import ProcessingConfig
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 572, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/qsuser/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/core/ProcessingConfig.py", line 30, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QPyNullVariant, QCoreApplication, QSettings
ImportError: cannot import name QPyNullVariant
```

I don't know what I am missing.

**Settings :**

```
Qgis 2.12.1-Lyon
Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty
IDE : Pycharm 5 community
Processing : 2.12.2
```

---

And with the changes suggest by mathias kuhn

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

def main():
    layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/file.shp', "BAT","ogr")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

    # Testing processing
    try :
        Processing.runalg("qgis:creategrid")
    except:
        print "Processing module has not been loaded"

    #Check the QgsMapLayerRegistry for the layers
    print QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    # Check if they are valid
    print layer.isValid()

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    from qgis.core import *        
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    app = QApplication([])
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    sys.path.append('home/user/.qgis2/python/plugins')

    # try to load processing
    try:
        from processing.core.Processing import Processing
        Processing.initialize()

    except:
        print "unable to load processing"

    main()

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error

```
ImportError: cannot import name QPyNullVariant
```

It indicates that the SIP API version is not set to version 2. When you write standalone python scripts, make sure that the very first import is

```
import qgis
```

The SIP API Version always needs to be set before any other PyQt code is executed. The qgis import takes care of that.