# Adding shapefile using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, shapefile, standalone

I am trying to add a Shapefile outside of the QGIS environment using PyQGIS. Ideally this would be done without creating a map in QGIS. I've started with the code below but am receiving the following error:

`QObject::connect: Cannot connect <null>::raiseError< QString > to QgsVectorLayer::raiseError< QString >`

Does the command below create a new map canvas?

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

layer = QgsVectorLayer("F:\\IrrigatedLands\\FC_qgis\\boundary.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")
#if not layer.isValid():
  #print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Comment: No it doesn't, You need to create an Qgis instance. follow the steps describe here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/176821/41673

Comment: Make sure you set your PATH and PYTHONPATH correctly before running the above as described [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102). Once they're set, your above code should work fine =)

Comment: I answered your (to this date) unsolved question. Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it did. I had to initialize the QgsApplication. Although when changing the script to a more complex geoprocess following the initialization lines, python crashes per the following post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189735/how-to-iterate-over-layers-and-export-them-as-png-images-with-pyqgis-in-a-standa

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you intend to run PyQGIS scripts out of QGIS, you need to initialize a `QgsApplication` so that it loads data providers and other resources. The following code snippet should work:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\", True) # Adjust prefix path according to your installation (see note below)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

layer = QgsVectorLayer("F:\\IrrigatedLands\\FC_qgis\\boundary.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"
```

Now you can start doing anything with your valid Shapefile, even without a map canvas.

*Note: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155852/4972 for more details about setting a prefix path on both Windows and GNU/Linux.*

Comment: in QGIS 3.x use `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication` instead of `from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication`

Answer (score 3):

I tried out this code (for my own shapefile and operative Linux system) and it was successfully:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

layer = QgsVectorLayer("/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"

else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

In your case, try out:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

layer = QgsVectorLayer("F:/IrrigatedLands/FC_qgis/boundary.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"

else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

If the layer failed to load then, your path is probably wrong.

Comment: I am able to execute `from qgis.core import *` and `import qgis.utils` with no errors in the OSGeo4W shell but adding the layer I am still getting `QObject::connect: Cannot connect <null>::raiseError< QString > to QgsVectorLayer::raiseError< QString >` The above script works in the Python console within QGIS