# Importing QGIS Processing in stand-alone python script?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I want to write a few stand-alone scripts that use the processing toolbox of Qgis.

I have read a few threads ([here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176821/pyqgis-couldnt-import-processing-with-standalone-script) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-can-i-access-processing-with-python), e.g.) but couldn't find a working solution yet.

Using Qgis 2.16.1 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS

The import section of my script looks like this:

```
# Python modules
import sys
import time
import os

# Qgis modules
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings
```

Does anyone know what is missing for me to be able to import the processing module?

With a simple *import processing*, I get this:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/steph/Documents/Projets/20141227-CIM_Bishkek/Scripts/python/00-projets/20160811-AnalysesUAVs/20160811-UAVAnalyse.py", line 36, in <module>
import processing
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 607, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named processing
```

EDIT (after Joseph's comment)

I have tried like this:

```
# Python modules
import sys
import time
import os

# Qgis modules
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
app = QApplication([])
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings
#from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# Prepare processing framework 
sys.path.append('/home/steph/.qgis2/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *
```

but the behavior is weird: my script runs until the end without error but seems to "jump" over the the tasks it's supposed to perform :-) In other words, it runs until the end but without doing anything.

I admit that my explanation is not very clear... I will investigate further but if anyone has a magical solution (not a workaround) to import this module, then please!

EDIT 2: adding my whole script. Sorry if it's a bit long....

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
########################################################
## Name: Performs various analyses on UAV imagery using Qgis
## Source Name: UAVanalyse.py
## Version: Python 2.7
## Author: Stephane Henriod
## Usage: Performs a set of analyses on UAV imagery
## Date 11.08.2016
## Modified: 
########################################################


# Import required modules

# Python modules
import sys
import time
import os

# Qgis modules
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings

# Custom modules
from config_work import *
import display_msg as disp
import clean_time as cl

def make_raster_layer(raster, log_file):
    """Creates a raster layer from the path to a raster, if the path exists and if the raster is valid

    Param_in:
        raster (string) -- The path to the raster to be transformed into a layer
        log_file (string) -- The path to the log file to write in

    Param_out:
        list: 
            [0] = full path to the raster 
            [1] = raster layer

    """

    if os.path.exists(raster):
        fileName = raster
        fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
        baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
        if rlayer.isValid():
            return [raster, rlayer]
    else:
        return False

def study_raster(rlayer, log_file):
    """Returns properties of a raster, if this one exists and is valid

    Param_in:
        rlayer (bin) -- A raster layer
        log_file (string) -- The path to the log file to write in

    """

    infos = {}

    if rlayer:
        infos['a - Width'] = rlayer.width()
        infos['b - Height'] = rlayer.height()
        infos['c - Extent'] = rlayer.extent().toString()
        infos['d - # bands'] = rlayer.bandCount()
        infos['e - X resolution'] = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
        infos['f - Y resolution'] = rlayer.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
        return infos
    else:
        return False


def project_raster(raster, to_crs, log_file):
    """Projects a raster into another crs

    Param_in:
        raster (string) -- The path to the raster to be transformed into a layer
        to_crs (string) -- The coordinate reference system to which the layer must be projected
        log_file (string) -- The path to the log file to write in

    """

    img_out_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(raster))[0] + '_proj' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(raster))[1]
    img_out = os.path.join(output_folder, img_out_name)
    #processing.runalg("gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:32642 -t_srs " + to_crs + " " + rlayer[0] + " " + img_out)

    msg = img_out    
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')

    return img_out_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t_start_script = time.localtime()
    t_start_script_clean = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M", t_start_script)

    # Checking the folders
    if not os.path.exists(input_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(input_folder_path)
    if not os.path.exists(temp_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(temp_folder_path)
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path):
        os.makedirs(output_folder_path)

    # Creating the output and temp folders
    output_folder = os.path.join(output_folder_path, t_start_script_clean + '-UAVanalyse')
    temp_folder = os.path.join(temp_folder_path, t_start_script_clean + '-UAVanalyse')

    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    if not os.path.exists(temp_folder):
        os.makedirs(temp_folder)

    # Creating the log file
    log_file_name = t_start_script_clean + '-UAVanalyse.log'
    log_file = os.path.join(output_folder, log_file_name)

    # Heading of the log file
    msg = "Performs a set of analyses on UAV imagery" + os.linesep
    msg += "Input folder: " + input_folder_path
    msg += "\n RGB image: " + img_rgb_name
    msg += "\n NIR image: " + img_nir_name
    msg += "\n RGBIR image: " + img_rgbir_name
    msg += "\n DSM file: " + img_dsm_name
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'w')

    #msg = "Script started on " + cl.clean_time(t_start_script)
    #disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')


    # Initialize Qgis (source: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html)
    msg = 'Initialize Qgis'
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')
    # supply path to qgis install location
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)

    # create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
    # second argument to False disables the GUI
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

    # load providers
    qgs.initQgis()


    # Write your code here to load some layers, use processing algorithms, etc.

    # Make raster layers
    rlayer_rgb = make_raster_layer(img_rgb, log_file)
    rlayer_nir = make_raster_layer(img_nir, log_file)
    rlayer_rgbir = make_raster_layer(img_rgbir, log_file)
    rlayer_dsm = make_raster_layer(img_dsm, log_file)

    all_valid_layers = []
    if rlayer_rgb: all_valid_layers.append(rlayer_rgb)
    if rlayer_nir: all_valid_layers.append(rlayer_nir)
    if rlayer_rgbir: all_valid_layers.append(rlayer_rgbir)
    if rlayer_dsm: all_valid_layers.append(rlayer_dsm)




    # (I) Infos about the layers
    msg = os.linesep + frm_separator + os.linesep + '(I) Infos about the layers' + os.linesep + frm_separator + os.linesep
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')

    i = 1
    for layer in all_valid_layers:
        infos = study_raster(layer[1], log_file)
        msg = '\n (' + str(i) + ') ' + layer[0] + os.linesep
        for item in sorted(infos):
            msg += '\n ' + str(item) + ': ' + str(infos[item]) + os.linesep

        i+=1
        disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')

    msg = 'List of valid layers:' + os.linesep
    for layer in all_valid_layers:
        msg += layer[0]+ os.linesep
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')


    # (II) Projects the layers into the national coordinate system or any desired system
    msg = os.linesep + frm_separator + os.linesep + '(II) Projecting of the layers' + os.linesep + frm_separator + os.linesep
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')

    i = 1
    for layer in all_valid_layers:
        project_raster(layer[0], to_crs, log_file)




    # When script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
    # layer registries from memory
    qgs.exitQgis()
    msg = 'Qgis has been closed'
    disp.display_msg(log_file, msg, 'a')

    #raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: In your second link, did you use the code provided by @GermánCarrillo? His code is what I also use to run standalone scripts (I edit my paths slightly as I use Windows).

Comment: What is the task you are trying to perform? :). Could you include the code in your question please? This could help others identify what is wrong.

Comment: I am trying to script a few functions to process UAV images. The first thing I need to do is to reproject, which is why I need the processing module. Let me add my full script, although I'm a bit ashamed: I'm not a "real" developer and I'm sure my code is not the cleanest or the most straight-forward you have ever seen :-)

Comment: Don't be ashamed! Nothing I post is the most cleanest or straight-forward =)

Comment: So I added my whole script. Feel free to have a look :-)

Comment: If you're looking to do the same in Python3 / QGIS 3:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/311957

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i managed to get it working, thanks @Joseph for your hints:

```
# Import required modules

# Python modules
import sys
import time
import datetime
import os
from getpass import getuser

# Qgis modules and environment
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
app = QApplication([])

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()

# Prepare processing framework
sys.path.append('/home/' + getuser() + '/.qgis2/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()
```

And I coud test it with

```
print Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:creategrid")
```

My issue, I guess, comes from the fact that I imported the modules at the beginning of my script and then tried create the Qgi obkects from within a function. I guess it would be possible to do so as well but there is probably a flaw in my Python skills.

Now I'll try to actually ust the processing module :-)

Comment: Something has changed ?  I try this code (from Joseph) to use processing into a standalone script   and  I  get: ImportError: No module named processing.core.Processing
Using linux QGIS 2.18.1

Answer (score 7):

Linux QGIS 2.18.1

With this code a got it, run Processing from standalone script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
import sys

app = QgsApplication([],True, None)
app.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
app.initQgis()
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
from processing.tools import *

print Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:creategrid")
```

Comment: This is the only combination that worked for the environment I am working in (Pycharm C.Ed on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine with Python 2.7). Before, I tried the combinations of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-can-i-access-processing-with-python, and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176821/pyqgis-couldnt-import-processing-with-standalone-script and sadly, none of them imported "processing.core.Processing". I dont know why importing a module is that confusing. For the record: there is a pure Python package also called "processing" that shadows the QGIS one.

Comment: man!! 

     sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')

worked like a charm after many trials!!