# No module name processing (Ubuntu Xenial)

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-processing, ubuntu

I had installed QGIS with it in ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

refer to this guide : https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

then i try to import QGIS module that usually work in Windows QGIS Desktop application such as :

```
from qgis.core import *
from osgeo import *
```

but then, i try to :

```
import processing
```

and it said:

```
No module named processing
```

Ok i see since this is run as external application, so i try to do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
import processing
```

but what i've got is:

```
QPixmap: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Then i my python console was exited automatically

So my question is, how to `import processing` in ubuntu python console that had been QGIS installed?

I really need this module..

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206620/importing-qgis-processing-in-stand-alone-python-script, because if you are not inside qgis, you need a standalone python script which initializes the qgis "environment".

Comment: but everytime i do this QApplication([]), it said "cannot connect to X server"

Comment: uhh, all right, you are on telnet/ssh connection? There are gui components, which need access the X-Window. Don't know exactly what to do in such a case.

Comment: i found this, if the above is the case: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-cannot-connect-to-X-server-on-Ubuntu-td5177029.html

Comment: i use ubuntu in virtualenv by the way..

Comment: @AndreasMüller Thanks.. i found the answer in your link..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to this link, 
http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-cannot-connect-to-X-server-on-Ubuntu-td5177029.html

This is how to import processing

```
import os 
import sys 

qgisprefix = '/usr' 
#qgisprefix='/usr/share/qgis/resources' 

# configure paths for QGIS 
sys.path.insert(0, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python') 
sys.path.insert(1, qgisprefix+'/share/qgis/python/plugins') 

# disable QGIS debug messages 
#os.environ['QGIS_DEBUG'] = '-1' 
os.environ['DISPLAY']="" 
# import QGIS modules 
from qgis.core import * 

#from qgis.gui import * 

# configure QGIS paths 
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgisprefix, False) 

# initalise QGIS 
QgsApplication.initQgis() 

app = QgsApplication([], False) 

import processing
```