# Importing QGIS3 processing tools in standalone script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

Inspired by [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206620/importing-qgis-processing-in-stand-alone-python-script), but for QGIS 3 (and therefore Python 3), I would like to use the QGIS processing algorithms in a standalone Python script without a GUI, with a standard installation of Ubuntu Linux.

A simple `import processing` is insufficient:

```
import processing
processing.run(
   "qgis:rasterlayerstatistics",
   {
       'INPUT': .'/somefile.tif',
       'BAND': 1,
       'OUTPUT_HTML_FILE': './result.html'
   }
)
```

Results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing'
```

How do you get access to the QGIS `processing` module to use the QGIS processing algorithms in a standalone Python script (not the QGIS interpreter)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module name processing (Ubuntu Xenial)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272274/no-module-name-processing-ubuntu-xenial)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of getting access to `processing` to run the QGIS "raster statistics" process, which returns useful information about a raster layer. In particular, raster statistics is useful for obtaining the sum of all values in a raster, which (AFAIK) cannot be done in GDAL alone.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import warnings
from functools import wraps


def ignore_warnings(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
            warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
            response = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return inner


def import_qgis_processing():
    sys.path.append('/usr/lib/qgis')
    sys.path.append('/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins')
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProcessingFeedback, QgsRasterLayer
    app = QgsApplication([], False)
    feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()
    return (app, feedback, QgsRasterLayer)


app, feedback, QgsRasterLayer = import_qgis_processing()
app.initQgis()


@ignore_warnings # Ignored because we want the output of this script to be a single value, and "import processing" is noisy
def initialise_processing(app):
    from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
    import processing
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
    Processing.initialize()
    app.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())
    return (app, processing,)


def check_input_validity(QgsRasterLayer):
    raster = QgsRasterLayer(sys.argv[1], 'raster', 'gdal')
    if not raster.isValid():
        raise Exception('Invalid raster')


def raster_stats():
    params = {
        'INPUT': sys.argv[1],
        'BAND': 1
    }
    return processing.run(
        "qgis:rasterlayerstatistics",
        params, feedback=feedback
    )


def get_raster_stat(stat='SUM'):
    return raster_stats().get(stat)


app, processing = initialise_processing(app)
check_input_validity(QgsRasterLayer)
print(get_raster_stat(stat=sys.argv[2]))
app.exitQgis()
```

The `ignore_warnings` wrapper function is included because without it there are three deprecation warnings emitted when importing `processing`, and I wanted the script to have a simple output to stdout. You can leave that out if desired.

Importing modules within functions is done to control the order of import, and to stop linters (e.g. `autopep8`) from attempting to move all import statements to the top.

The key places to include in `sys.path` are:

- `/usr/lib/qgis`
- `/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins`

These would be different on different operating systems, and probably in different Linux distributions.

This script can be run like: `./rasterstats.py ./somefile.tif SUM`, and it would output the sum of all values in the raster to stdout (ignoring no-data values if present). `MAX`, `MIN`, etc. work also.

The key functions are `import_qgis_processing` and `initialise_processing`.

Comment: For windows, in import_qgis_processing(), use this path, "<qgis install folder>\apps\<qgis or qgis-ltr depending on install>\python\plugins"