# Import Processing Toolbox in PyQGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, linux, toolbox

I am trying to import processing toolbox in my standalone PyQGIS application. But I am in trouble. I follow this instruction:
[Importing QGIS Processing in stand-alone python script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206620/importing-qgis-processing-in-stand-alone-python-script/219847) and this [Using QGIS3 Processing algorithms from standalone PyQGIS scripts (outside of GUI)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279874/using-qgis3-processing-algorithms-from-standalone-pyqgis-scripts-outside-of-gui/279937#279937)

```
sys.path.append('/home/' + getuser() + '/.qgis3/python/plugins')
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
```

But PyCharm doesn't recognize processing still. :/ I suppose it is because of the path, but I don't know where to point anymore.
I am using QGIS 3.0 and Linux Ubuntu.

UPDATE: I tried now this path: /home/usrer/.qgis3/python/plugins
After that, I got the option to install package, which I run. But after running it, I got the error:

```
Collecting processing
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3b/2d/a6f17cc99d9c45c33eb3eccd6999505d9197b31f0845a845919032262a01/processing-0.52.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging401/processing/setup.py", line 12
    raise ValueError, 'Versions of Python before 2.4 are not supported'
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging401/processing/
```

And installation failed.
And when I try it to install from terminal with: 
    sudo pip3 install processing 
I get the same error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I succeed. I just copy processing folder into script folder and delete line sys.path.append