# Script PyQGIS without Interface in Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, ubuntu

please can you help me? I tried many times to do a script of pyqgis but without interface qgis. I use QGIS 3.6.3 and Ubuntu 18.04, does Somebody know do this?

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206620/importing-qgis-processing-in-stand-alone-python-script