# PyQGIS Error: Cannot Create a QPixmap or Qwidget when no GUI is being used

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

I am trying to create a standalone script using the code below. I was able to add a shapefile with no errors but when I add `map = QgsMapCanvas()` after `qgs.initQgis()` and `map.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])` after `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)` I get the following errors: `Cannot Create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used` and `Cannot Create a Qwidget when no GUI is being used`

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface

import sys, os

qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
qgis_prefix = "C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis"
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(qgis_prefix, True)
qgs.initQgis()

map = QgsMapCanvas()

layer = QgsVectorLayer("F:/IrrigatedLands/FC_qgis/boundary.shp", "testlayer_shp", "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"

else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

map.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])

print layer
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter of the `QgsApplication` enables/disables the QGIS GUI components in your script. Just change it to true:

```
qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)
```

Comment: LOL this answers the comment I had on another answer of yours at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/how-can-i-access-processing-with-python/130337#comment281594_130337

Comment: That's hilarious! Glad to know your question was solved (I had no idea). Could you please answer your comment there for future readers?