# Running QGIS script in external Python code gives TypeError?

Tags: pyqgis, standalone, typeerror

- I have one piece of Python code that I wrote in QGIS 3.6 (I'll call this code1)
- and I have a second piece of Python code that is a bigger project, which I wrote just in a normal text programme and which I run through the terminal of my xubuntu (I'll call this code2)

They both work seperately in QGIS / the terminal.
Now I want to combine them - code2 should at some point call code1 and run it as well. I don't want to open QGIS and run the code, everything should be done as one single process.

So I copied code1 into code2. Then I wrote this at the beginning of code2

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/share/qgis/",True)
qgs = QgsApplication([],False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

When the code reaches the first QGis function

```py
params_proj = {
    "INPUT": layerinput_proj,
    "TARGET_CRS":"EPSG:4326", 
    "OUTPUT":("/media/vali/project/geodaten/gem_proj.shp")
    }
feedback=QgsProcessingFeedback()    
res_proj=QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(u"native:reprojectlayer", params_proj, feedback=feedback)
res_proj["OUTPUT"]
```

I get this error:

```py
TypeError: QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Why does the code work in QGIS but not when I run it through the terminal?

I searched the Internet and could not find any solutions that work for me or that I can understand, as I am quite a beginner.

Since someone asked, here is a larger bit of my code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3
import openpyxl, os, csv
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, pandas as pd, geopandas as gpd, csv
from qgis.core import *# supply path to qgis install location
from qgis.gui import *
import qgis.utils


#------------------------------------------------------------------------
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/share/qgis/",True)
# create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([],False)
# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

#sys.path.append('/docs/dev/qgis/build/output/python/plugins')

path="/media/valentina/0bc36d5e-1c60-4266-a1ef-a284ac0b5315/project/geodaten/"

#-------------- change projection of gem shape -------------
layerinput_proj=QgsVectorLayer((path+"STATISTIK_AUSTRIA_GEM_20190101Polygon.shp"), "proj", "ogr")

params_proj = {
    "INPUT": layerinput_proj,
    "TARGET_CRS":"EPSG:4326", 
    "OUTPUT":(path+"gem_proj.shp")
    }
feedback=QgsProcessingFeedback()    
res_proj=QgsProcessingAlgRunnerTask(u"native:reprojectlayer", params_proj, feedback=feedback)
res_proj["OUTPUT"]

#-------------- calculate centroids -------------
layerinput=QgsVectorLayer((path+"gem_proj.shp"), "Gemshape", "ogr")

params = {
    "INPUT": layerinput,
    "ALL_PARTS":False, 
    "OUTPUT":(path+"gem_centroid.shp")
    }

res=processing.run("native:centroids", params, feedback=feedback)
res["OUTPUT"]

#-------------- reproject centroids -------------
layerinput_proj=QgsVectorLayer((path+"gem_centroid.shp"), "proj", "ogr")
params_proj2 = {
    "INPUT": layerinput_proj,
    "TARGET_CRS":"EPSG:4326", 
    "OUTPUT":(path+"gem_centroid_proj.shp")
    }

res_proj2=processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", params_proj2, feedback=feedback)
res_proj2["OUTPUT"]

#-------------- calculate geometry attributes -------------
layerinput_geom=QgsVectorLayer((path+"gem_centroid_proj.shp"), "gem_centroid", "ogr")

params_geom = {
    "INPUT": layerinput_geom,
    "CALC_METHOD":0, 
    "OUTPUT":(path+"gem_centroid_geom.shp")
    }

res_geom=processing.run("qgis:exportaddgeometrycolumns", params_geom, feedback=feedback)
res_geom["OUTPUT"]

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? I'd like to see whether/how you are importing `QgsNativeAlgorithms`.

Comment: I edited the original post and pasted a larger part of my code

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the QGIS application (`qgs` in your code):

```py
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize() # This will emit some warnings that you can ignore
qgs.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

res_proj = processing.run("qgis:reprojectlayer", layerinput_proj,"EPSG:4326", "/media/vali/project/geodaten/gem_proj.shp")
```

This is untested. Note that the *order* of imports is important. This is an area QGIS can be improved. In particular, you need to import `processing` after the call to `initQgis()`. I have a gist to do something similar [here](https://gist.github.com/alpha-beta-soup/a628239f48dd64209440657fb65b8fab). Sometimes linters like to move all imports to the top of a file and change their order, so I place sequence-sensitive imports in a function and call them when appropriate.

Comment: I put this at the beginning of my code, but now I get this error (for line 2 in your post):  
" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing' "  

--- Do I have to install something?

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I said, the order of imports is important. Try to `import processing` *after* all of your original imports.

Comment: There are several related questions at this point: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129513/accessing-processing-with-python

Comment: Surely (for QGIS 3.x) the call to processing.run should only have two arguments, the second of which being a dictionary of parameters?

Comment: Correct. I did say it was untested. The main demonstration here is getting access to `processing` at all. Feel free to edit it.